# Extend D3 chart to add zoom functionality

Tags: d3.js

I am using an external javascript library to generate D3 SVG charts inside an ASP.NET application. The library accepts div container and creates a D3 chart inside the div container. The D3 chart is currently static. I would like add zoom functionality. Is it possible to extend the D3 chart generated by the external javascript library to add zoom in feature?

Generated SVG:

```
<div id="svgContainer2" style="margin-left: 15px;">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
      <g>
         <circle style="fill: #b8dee6;" cx="831.5" cy="50" r="50" />
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

I tried below code but no luck:

```
<input type="button" value="Zoom" id="btnZ" onclick="addZoom();" />

    function addZoom() {

        var svg = d3.select("svg");
        svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution : Working Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Create a div where the circle will take place -->
<div id="svgContainer2" style="margin-left: 15px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <g><circle style="fill: #b8dee6;" cx="333" cy="333" r="50" /></g>
</svg>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("#svgContainer2 svg g")
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}))
</script>
</html>
```